# Select node based on child node value in Web.config Transform

Tags: .net, xpath, web-config, web-config-transform, slowcheetah

I have the following XML in my web config and I would like to select an attribute for removal using web.config transforms, but I would like to select the element for removal based on the value of one of the child elements.

My web.config is something like this:

```
<configuration>
   <sitecore>
       <scheduling>
          <agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent">
             <param desc="database">core</param>
          </agent>
          <agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent">
             <param desc="database">master</param>
          </agent>
       </scheduling>
    </sitecore>
 </configuration>
```

I have tried the following to try to select the second agent element for deletion based on the child element `<param desc="database">master</param>` but with no success.

```
<configuration>
   <sitecore>
       <scheduling>
          <!-- Attempt 1 -->
          <agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent"
                 xdt:Transform="Remove"
                 xdt:Locator="XPath(configuration/sitecore/scheduling/agent/param[text()='master'])"/>

          <!-- Attempt 2 -->
          <agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent"
                 xdt:Transform="Remove">
             <param desc="database"
                    xdt:Locator="XPath([text()='master'])"/>
          </agent>
       </scheduling>
    </sitecore>
 </configuration>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707108/xdt-transform-locator-that-matches-subnode-content/9707298) the `xdt:Locator` attribute needs to use the `Condition` syntax.  So the required selector is:

```
<agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent"
       xdt:Transform="Remove"
       xdt:Locator="Condition(param/@desc='database' and param/text()='master')" />
```

Comment: If you want to match `<param desc='database'>master</param>`, this xpath will be more accurate: `param[@desc='database']/text()='master'`.  Otherwise, you could potentially match `<agent><param desc="database" /><param>master</param></agent>`.

Answer (score 2):

Just use Sitecores own config patcher. This will remove your setting:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <scheduling>
       <agent patch:instead="*[@type='Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent' and param='master']">
       </agent>
    </scheduling>
 </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

For more information, look here:

http://intothecore.cassidy.dk/2009/05/working-with-webconfig-include-files-in.html
http://www.thescrewballdivision.com/playing-with-sitecore-include-files

Comment: The Sitecore patching feature isn't really what I want in this case as I want to use web.config transforms to create different web.config files based on environment. So one environment will remove the xml node, whereas it will be left as-is for another environment.

Answer (score -1):

Just add `/..` onto the end, that should do it..

e.g.

```
XPath(configuration/sitecore/scheduling/agent/param[text()='master']/..)
```

Comment: ...to the end of which one?

Comment: you may need `//` on the front, but if you can remove the `param` element with your selection, then the `/..` should do it