# Sitecore - patch node with the same attributes as the others

Tags: search, attributes, sitecore, nodes, patch

how can I patch specified node if there are several other nodes with the same attributes?

I need to patch analyzer for czech language in ContentSearch section, but all nodes start with

<mapEntry type="**Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.PerExecutionContextAnalyzerMapEntry, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider**">

Part of that configuration looks like this

```
...</maEntry>
<mapEntry type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.PerExecutionContextAnalyzerMapEntry, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
  <param hint="executionContext" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.CultureExecutionContext, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
    <param hint="cultureInfo" type="System.Globalization.CultureInfo, mscorlib">
      <param hint="name">ar-AE</param>
    </param>
  </param>
  <param desc="analyzer" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.DefaultPerFieldAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
    <param desc="defaultAnalyzer" type="Lucene.Net.Analysis.AR.ArabicAnalyzer, Lucene.Net.Contrib.Analyzers">
      <param hint="version">Lucene_30</param>
    </param>
  </param>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.PerExecutionContextAnalyzerMapEntry, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
  <param hint="executionContext" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.CultureExecutionContext, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
    <param hint="cultureInfo" type="System.Globalization.CultureInfo, mscorlib">
      <param hint="name">pt-BR</param>
    </param>
  </param>
  <param desc="analyzer" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.DefaultPerFieldAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
    <param desc="defaultAnalyzer" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.Contrib.BrazilianAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
      <param hint="version">Lucene_30</param>
    </param>
  </param>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.PerExecutionContextAnalyzerMapEntry, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
  <param hint="executionContext" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.CultureExecutionContext, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
    <param hint="cultureInfo" type="System.Globalization.CultureInfo, mscorlib">
      <param hint="name">cs-CZ</param>
    </param>
  </param>
  <param desc="analyzer" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.DefaultPerFieldAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
    <param desc="defaultAnalyzer" type="Lucene.Net.Analysis.Cz.CzechAnalyzer, Lucene.Net.Contrib.Analyzers">
      <param hint="version">Lucene_30</param>
    </param>
  </param>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>...
```

And I need to patch (in our example) **defaultAnalyzer in second node**. BUT second node is not in real life SECOND, but it could be third, seventh etc... I guess I need to find "mapEntry" node by specified inner node.

If I use this

```
<map hint="list:Add">
    <!-- Patch analyzer for Czech language -->
    <mapEntry type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.PerExecutionContextAnalyzerMapEntry, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
        <param desc="analyzer" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.DefaultPerFieldAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
            <param desc="defaultAnalyzer" type="Lucene.Net.Analysis.Cz.CzechAnalyzer, Lucene.Net.Contrib.Analyzers">
                <patch:attribute name="type">MySolution.MetroAsciiFoldingAnalyzer, MySolution</patch:attribute>
            </param>
        </param>
    </mapEntry>
</map>
```

It will patch first node.

I found something similar in this issue [Select node based on child node value in Web.config Transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14719214/select-node-based-on-child-node-value-in-web-config-transform), but as I understand I would replace whole one node with my custom one, but .... it is necessary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer you linked to uses [SlowCheetah](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) to do it's transforms, and I presume you are trying to do this using [Sitecore config patch](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2011/05/All-About-Web-config-Include-Files-with-the-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS.aspx)...

Because you are selecting a node based on a child value, you can use the `contains` function to check for a value. But you can only patch that specific node, you can't select it for a query. So you would essentially have to replace the whole node.

I suggest you first delete the existing `cs-CZ` entry and then add in your own. Note that I had to make the `mapEntry` node more unique so I added a `desc` attribute, otherwise it overwrites the first match (in this case ja-JP)

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" >
   <sitecore>
    <contentSearch>
       <indexConfigurations>
         <defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration>
          <analyzer>
            <param desc="map">
              <map>

                <mapEntry patch:instead="*[contains(.,'cs-CZ')]">
                  <patch:delete />                 
                </mapEntry>

                <mapEntry desc="cs-CZ Analyzer" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.PerExecutionContextAnalyzerMapEntry, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
                  <param hint="executionContext" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.CultureExecutionContext, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
                    <param hint="cultureInfo" type="System.Globalization.CultureInfo, mscorlib">
                      <param hint="name">cs-CZ</param>
                    </param>
                  </param>
                  <param desc="analyzer" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.DefaultPerFieldAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
                    <param desc="defaultAnalyzer" type="MySolution.MetroAsciiFoldingAnalyzer, MySolution">
                      <param hint="version">Lucene_30</param>
                    </param>
                  </param>
                </mapEntry>

              </map>
            </param>
          </analyzer>     
        </defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration>
      </indexConfigurations>
    </contentSearch>
   </sitecore>
</configuration>
```